# AngularJs Render div onclick

Tags: angularjs

If I'm having this code below. How can I render the div(#divToRender) when clicking the button. I know there is angularJs code for hide/show. But I dont want it to be rendered until I click my button. Is that possible? //Thanks

```
<button>Render my div!</button

<div id="divToRender">
    Some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ng-if`, it will render the element only if the expression is evaluated to true.

```
<button ng-click="showMyDiv = true">Render my div!</button>

<div id="divToRender" ng-if="showMyDiv">
    Some text
</div>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jtasEuhNCghprsGZjSrh?p=preview

Also see [ngIf documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

Comment: thank you for the answer. How can I bind the "false/true" so it changes when I click the button?

Comment: You could use `ng-click` as show in the example above.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how. Can you please give me a example? thank you

Comment: The example already in the code above, please see `<button ng-click="showMyDiv = true">`.

Comment: An example plunker has been included.

Comment: Alright! Sorry I did a typo. Everything works perfect now. Thank you!